# Journey using Salesforce Data: Not able to create filter on the same object used for the entry event

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to create a multi-step journey using Salesforce Data as entry event. My target object is Opportunity and the audience is primary contact within the opp. The entry criteria is when the opp stage is updated to 'Closed Won'. The problem is, we have multiple record types in opportunities that are related to different business units in Marketing Cloud. I want to create a filter to a specific record type and product type on the opportunity so that the records with other record types get excluded from the entry DE and journey. In the Filter Criteria, all I can see is the other related objects to the opportunity but not the opportunity fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you can filter off the records within the **Entry Criteria** option on the opportunity object itself. Given that the Record Type ID itself won't change, this will mean that during the moment this record is being updated to 'Closed Won' - it will qualify for the journey.

One thing to note, the record trigger in Salesforce data event type is based on the true/false state of the record. Therefore, to qualify for the records to enter the journey both Opp stage and Record Type ID has to match exactly with your filter criteria in the Entry Source.

In the event, if another Record Type ID with Opp stage as 'Closed Won' comes along, it won't qualify for the journey.

I hope this helps.

Reference: [The Salesforce Data Event](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_salesforce_data_event.htm&type=5)

Comment: It seems that marketing cloud is looking only for the stage field to be updated and the rest of the fields are considered as filters as they never get updated. However, it's working the way I wanted. Thanks!